# BackGround Task not working in a window phone 8 beta app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have created a Window phone 8 app. Which changes the lockscreen image and notification in around 30 sec randomly.

My code works well in the emulator and device. When I install it through the code. My problem is that when I have submitted the app to the store as a beta app. And now I install the app from the store the app don't work as it was working. The lockscreen content don't change it remains static. I have checked  the settings background agents that app is running in the background tasks but not showing the result.

What could be the cause that app is running well from the code but not from the xap uploaded to the store.

Link of app is http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=00d47e34-a551-4c98-b2a6-32e10babdc2f
 am I missing any capability that need to fixed.

Your suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your title says you are using a background task and you are trying to do something every 30 secs, I assume that you're using `ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest` to trigger your background task and which then performs the updating.

`ScheduledActionService.LaunchForTest` is only supported in DEBUG builds as a way to aid testing. It is not possible to submit an app to the store that is built in DEBUG mode so this will not work.

It is not possible to create an app which will update so often in the background. To have such an app would, potentially, drain the battery really quickly and so provide a very poor experience to users.

The best you can do is to have the background agent run on a periodic schedule (approx. every 30 mins) or trigger the updates via push notifications. (But this wouldn't work for the lock screen image.)